# Get parent row which is followed by the child rows

Tags: mysql, sql

The other parent->child answers I've found don't really seem to address my situation so here goes.

```
left-right-connections
cid    leftId     rightId
1      1          1
2      1          2
3      1          3
4      2          4
5      3          5
5      3          6

left
id    desc
1     RED
2     GREEN
3     BLUE

right
id   desc
1    car
2    train
3    helicopter
4    truck
5    boat
6    roller skates
```

What I need is assistance with creating the query that would return something like this

```
cid    leftId     rightId   desc
        1                   RED
  1     1            1      car
  2     1            2      train
  3     1            3      helicopter
        2                   GREEN
  4     2            4      truck
        3                   BLUE
  5     3            5      boat
  6     3            6      roller skates
```

I can get the joins to work but then I get all the leftId and right Id and desc in each row when what I need is for the left item to be the parent of all of the right item children.

I think what I need is a distinct for the leftId and then a subquery that gets all of the associated rightId items. I can do very basic sql, but this is over my head.

I hope what I've explained here makes sense.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first get distinct leftId data and then union with rightId data and sort by columns to get desired output. Is this something you need for display or UI?

[SQL FIDDLE with sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/920b9b/3)

Ex:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NULL AS CID, leftID, NULL AS rightId, b.descr
FROM leftrightT A
INNER JOIN leftT B on A.leftId = B.id
UNION ALL
SELECT CID, leftID, rightId, b.descr
FROM leftrightT A
INNER JOIN rightT B on A.rightId = B.id
order by leftId, CID
```

Comment: Yes, this will go into a table. Also, SQL Fiddle! How cool, thanks for that!

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. Here's my fiddle changed to some actual table names and columns  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5955ce1/1